# How to determine the smallest index under a special condition?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

In the following example:

```
          A     B
     1          bar
     2    3.0   foo
     3    4.0   foo
------------------------
     4    1.0   bar
------------------------
     5    2.0   bar
     6    5.0   bar 
     7          foo
```

I would like to get the smallest row index i (that is 4 in our case), for which `B(i)="bar"` and `A(i)` is not an empty cell. Could you please suggest a formula/VBA macro for this task?

Comment: What should happen if more than one row has the minimum value? What have you tried?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I need the very first row, where column B contains "bar" and the corresponding cell of column A is not empty. There is only such an index, I believe. I wanted to use `match`, but I don't know how to specify this criterion for it.

Comment: There is a way to use `MATCH` with multiple criteria. But in this case, `MINIFS` is much simpler.

Comment: No DV from me, but maybe you want to see [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-it-required-to-provide-comments-feedback-for-downvotes-and-why-are-pr) why providing feedback on DV's is actually discouraged @Gravitate The hover tip over the DV arrow says "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful." This is commentary enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A nice and simple `MINIFS` should do what you want.

```
=MINIFS($A$2:$A$8,$B$2:$B$8,"<>",$C$2:$C$8,"bar")
```

[image]

This just return the minimum index where A is not blank, and B is "bar".

**EDIT - Adding an alternative solution using `MATCH`**

Using `MATCH` is a little more complicated, but works on older versions of Excel and doesn't require the Index column like the previous example does:

```
=MATCH(1, INDEX(($B$2:$B$8<>"") * ($C$2:$C$8="bar"), 0, 1), 0)
```

[image]